# Wordpress and Jetpack filterable portfolio

Tags: php, html, wordpress, jquery-isotope, jetpack

So I followed this [tutorial](http://webdevstudios.com/2015/01/27/create-a-filterable-portfolio-with-wordpress-and-jetpack/#comment-63637) on how to use Wordpress, Jetpack, and Isotope to make a filterable portfolio of my projects I've done. I got the filter and project images to display just like the tutorial says it should. I think it works great.

My main issue right now is I only want to display my "Recent Websites" in my footer and only display the name, image, and brief content. I have done this a different way and it worked by creating a custom post type.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'projects', 'category_name' => 'websites', 'posts_per_page' => 2 );
```

Projects was a custom post type I created but since I followed that tutorial I got something all in one basically. Now again im trying to get only "2" of those recent websites to display at the footer of my [website](http://dev.ryanlebo.com) and this is how I did that.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'jetpack-portfolio', 'category_name' => 'websites', 'posts_per_page' => 2 );
```

When I view the website, nothing displays. I did more research and found out that "Jetpack-Portfolio" is a custom taxonomy and it's actually `jetpack-portfolio-type` but i'm trying to call it and nothing will work, OR it will display the two most recent projects I added to my site.

EDIT: I tried placing the pictures on here but my REP isn't high enough :P

SO my question is: how can I call that custom taxonomy to again display the websites only.

EDIT 7/16 @ 9:06pm ET

`<div class="Cfoot">
                <h2>Recent Websites</h2>
                <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'jetpack-portfolio', 'category_name' => 'websites', 'posts_per_page' => 2 );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); { ?>
                <section id="Recent-Web">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/Foot_Placeholder.png" width="75" height="75" align="left" />
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                </section>
                <?php } endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
            </div>`

EDIT 7/18

Ok so I was messing around with this some more and decided to change `category_name` to `category_slug` and now it seems to display 2 of my recent projects. That's fine but again I'm trying to only display from the `websites` category and not all of them. Here is my updated code.
`<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'jetpack-portfolio', 'category_slug' => 'websites', 'posts_per_page' => 2);` 
What can I do to only display JUST the slug `websites` and not most recent projects.

Comment: Could you post the part of the code where `$args` is called to be placed in your page?

Answer (score 1):

If you combine the data sets that Jetpack Portfolios create in your database with the [official WP_Query reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters), the solution should be:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'jetpack-portfolio',
            'tax_query'      => array(
                                  array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'jetpack-portfolio-type',
                                    'field'    => 'slug',
                                    'terms'    => 'websites'
                                  )
                                ),
            'posts_per_page' => 2
          );

  $loop = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```